# Decompress csv.gzip stored in S3 using lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I need to decompress a gzip file stored in S3. Decompressed file also will be stored in same S3 bucket.

What is the most productive way to decompress a gzip file?
Currently I use an aws lambda function to decompress.
But it takes around 1min to process a compressed csv which contains 100K rows.

I need to decompress gzip in 15 min which lambda max running duration.

Details of the current implementation of the lambda function:

```
# decompress the src on the fly
with smart_open.open(s3_gzip_path) as src:
    with smart_open.open(s3_dest_csv_path) as dest:
        batch = ''
        for row in src:
            batch += row
            if len(batch) > THRESHOLD:
                dest.write(batch)
                batch = ''
```

Comment: When you say "it takes 1min to read ~100K product", are you saying that you are currently reading the compressed file from within an AWS Lambda function using smart_open and attempting to process lines in the file, but it is taking too long? What is your current timeout setting? Does this lambda function process the file in some way, or is it there purely to decompress the file and store the decompressed file back into S3? More details, please.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I updated the context. It purely decompress the file and store the decompressed file back into S3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your AWS Lambda function should:

- Download the object from the Amazon S3 bucket to the `/tmp/` directory using [`download_file()` - Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/download_file.html)
- Use the [gzip — Support for gzip files — Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) library in Python to decompress the file
- Upload the decompressed file to S3 using [`upload_file()` - Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/upload_file.html)

All of this should only take a few seconds.

Please note that there is only a default of 512MB of storage in `/tmp/`, so delete the files after they have been uploaded to avoid filling up the storage space in future executions of the Lambda function.